# GCM send message to all devices

Tags: php, android, mysql, google-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with GCM, I can't send a message to all devices.

This isn't the original code, but is my own version!

**send_message.php:**

```
<?php  
if (isset($_POST["regId"]) && isset($_POST["message"])) {
//$regId = $_POST["regId"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

include './GCM.php';

$gcm = new GCM();

//$registatoin_ids = array($regId);
$message = array("price" => $message);


    include_once 'db_functions.php';

    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $users = $db->getAllUsers();

    if($users != false){
        $no_of_users = mysql_num_rows($users);
    }else{
        $no_of_users = 0;
    }


    $i = 0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
        $ids[$i] = $row["gcm_regid"];
        $i++;

        foreach ($ids as $value){
            echo $value;
            $registatoin_ids = $value;
            json_encode($registatoin_ids);
                $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
                echo $result;
    }
    }

echo $value;
echo $registatoin_ids;
}
?>
```

**GCM.php:**

```
<?php
class GCM {

//put your code here
// constructor
function __construct() {

}

/**
 * Sending Push Notification
 */
public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
    // include config
    include_once './config.php';

    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';



    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
 }
}
?>
```

**db_functions.php:**

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

private $db;

//put your code here
// constructor
function __construct() {
    include_once './db_connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $this->db = new DB_Connect();
    $this->db->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {

}

/**
 * Storing new user
 * returns user details
 */
public function storeUser($name, $email, $gcm_regid) {
    // insert user into database
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO gcm_users(name, email, gcm_regid, created_at) VALUES('$name', '$email', '$gcm_regid', NOW())");
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        // get user details
        $id = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gcm_users WHERE id = $id") or die(mysql_error());
        // return user details
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            return mysql_fetch_array($result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Get user by email and password
 */
public function getUserByEmail($email) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gcm_users WHERE email = '$email' LIMIT 1");
    return $result;
}

/**
 * Getting all users
 */
public function getAllUsers() {
    $result = mysql_query("select * FROM gcm_users");
    return $result;
}

/**
 * Check user is existed or not
 */
public function isUserExisted($email) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT email from gcm_users WHERE email = '$email'");
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        // user existed
        return true;
    } else {
        // user not existed
        return false;
    }
}

}

?>
```

The original code is from Ravi Tamada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change **send_message.php** to the bellow code :

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


 include_once 'db_functions.php';

if (isset($_GET["message"]) && isset($_GET["Number"])) {



    $message = $_GET["message"];


        $db = new DB_Functions();



        $users = $db->getAllUsers();
        $regIds = array();

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {

        array_push($regIds,$row['gcm_regid']);      
        }
        echo isset($users);
        if ($users != false)
            $no_of_users = mysql_num_rows($users);
        else
            $no_of_users = 0;


    include_once './GCM.php';

    $gcm = new GCM();

    $message = array("message" => $message);

    $result = $gcm->send_notification($regIds, $message);

    echo $result;
}
?>
```